# Why was my answer converted to a comment?

Tags: discussion

I provided a personal, first hand experience of not just interviews being made but much more time consuming (which is probably what the question is about) and yet my highly upvoted answer was moved to a comment. [Are passengers interviewed for Israeli domestic flights in the same way as they are for foreign ones?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/83793/are-passengers-interviewed-for-israeli-domestic-flights-in-the-same-way-as-they/83801?noredirect=1#comment195143_83793)

Funny thing is, I could undelete it because the numerous upvotes on this answer pushed me over 20K but I'd rather not.

Answer (score 2):

Fair question, and I wish we could provide a notification reason to the author when we do this to their answers.

It was flagged by a few people (And while you had upvotes, you fail to mention the multiple downvotes) as not an answer. As pnuts also says, while it's interesting, it doesn't seem to directly answer the question, and rather than delete it as was requested, I moved it to a comment.

Happy to debate it, potentially undelete it, but as it seemed to be more of an experience, rather than a comparison of Domestic and International interviews.

Comment: Are you OK if I resurrect with an edit similar to what @Rathony suggests in http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/a/4100/4188

Comment: @chx sounds good. Let me know if you have troubles resurrecting it.

Comment: yes, you need to undelete it, I can't override a moderator.

Comment: @chx done, please update as suggested :)

Answer (score 2):

It would have been better if you answered the question including a sentence along the lines of

> Yes, security interview is done for both international and domestic flights.
>
> No, security interview is done only for international flights.

I think your post answers the question, but for some users, your answer might not have been sufficient as an answer. What I would do on other sites where I am active is post another answer based on the comment. If you do it, I think you will get some upvotes including mine.